# Renomear Arquivo PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, excel-vba

Boa Tarde Comunidade,

Estou tentando criar uma macro que renomeie 125 arquivos em PDF que estão em uma pasta especifica C:... quero que ele substitua o nome que esta na minha coluna B... Tipo pegar os PDF na pasta depois renome los conforme minha planilha alguém sabe como fazer isso fiz varias pesquisas e até agora não consegui nada.

---

Obrigado pela ajuda mesmo

É meio tenso a pratica de mudança de linguagem já que estudo Java e passei a fazer VBA. Eu fiz o que sabia, mas peguei bastante dados de pesquisas no google.

No meu código, estou tendo que informar o nome do aquivo antigo e o novo, mas não teria um jeito de só colocar o novo, e outra não sei como já deixar os arquivos com .pdf... quando executo o código tenho que colocar manual.

Desculpe pelas perguntas... não tenho muito contato com VBA.

Desde já lhe agradeço muito por ter me ajudado.

```html
Sub RenameFiles()

Dim xDir As String
Dim xFile As String
Dim xRow As Long
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show = -1 Then
    xDir = .SelectedItems(1)
    xFile = Dir(xDir & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
    Do Until xFile = ""
        xRow = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        xRow = Application.Match(xFile, Range("A:A"), 0)
        If xRow > 0 Then
            Name xDir & Application.PathSeparator & xFile As _
            xDir & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(xRow, "B").Value
        End If
        xFile = Dir
    Loop
End If
End With
End Sub

Sub ListFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim j As Integer
MyFolder = "C:\Users\AnaWill\Desktop\Holerites Folha\Nova pasta"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.*")
a = 0
Do While MyFile <> ""
    a = a + 1
    Cells(a, 2).Value = MyFile
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

[image: Código VBA]

Comment: Ideal colocar o que já tentou fazer em vba... mas posso te dar uma luz... tente buscar um amacro para listar arquivos de uma pasta e ao listar poderá alterar o nome do arquivo. Aqui tem um modelo... http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/file/mp3_file_lister/ quando tiver acesso a um pc posso te ajudar com o código.

Comment: Certo, estou adequando seu código para rodar como precisa, mas fiquei com dúvida... serão sempre 125 arquivos? ou seja os nomes deverão ser exatamente 125 nomes na coluna "B" (B1:B125)? Os nomes "antigos" dos arquivos não importa? Nem a ordem?

Answer (score 2):

Veja se da forma como está te atende, fiz pequenos ajustes na sua fórmula onde coloquei comentário.

Para listar os arquivos de determinada pasta na coluna "A":

```
Sub listarArquivos()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim dialogFile As Integer

    ' Limpar coluna
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    ' Busca pasta onde estão os arquivos
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName _
    = "Selecionar pasta"
    dialogFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show

    ' Verifica se foi selecionado
    If dialogFile <> 0 Then
        MyFolder =Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Pasta não selecionada", vbInformation, "Aviso!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.pdf")
    a = 0
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        a = a + 1
        Cells(a, 1).Value = MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

> Adaptei a função acima do seu código, escolhendo a pasta na hora de executar a rotina, mas claro que pode deixar a pasta por padrão como fez.

Após listar os arquivos PDFs na coluna "A", coloquei o padrão dos novos nomes para os arquivos na célula "C1" e a seguinte fórmula na coluna "B":

Em "C1":

```
"novo_nome_do_arquivo"
```

Na coluna "B" (tendo a célula B1 como referência):

```
=SE(A1<>"";ESQUERDA(A1;PROCURAR("@";SUBSTITUIR(A1;"\";"@";(NÚM.CARACT(A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1;"\";"")))/NÚM.CARACT("\"))))&$C$1&LIN(A1)&".pdf";"")
```

> Essa fórmula gigante acima apenas identifica a última ocorrência de "\" (barra invertida) da coluna "A" e pega toda a *string*, que é o caminho onde o arquivo se encontra, mais o nome padrão definido em "C1" mais a extensão ".pdf".

E finalmente renomeia os arquivos que estão na coluna "A" para o nome definido na coluna "B":

```
Sub renomearArquivo()

Dim Row As Integer
Dim OldFile As String
Dim NewFile As String

    ' Somente o que estiver preenchido na coluna "A"
    For Row = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        OldFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1)
        NewFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 2)

        ' Renomear Arquivo
        Name OldFile As NewFile

    Next
End Sub
```

Adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508605/renaming-files-with-excel-vba

Segue imagem da planilha para ver como ficou aqui:

[image: Imagem da Planilha]

Espero ter ajudado!